# websocket.receive_text raise ValueError: The future belongs to a different loop than the one specified as the loop argument

Tags: asynchronous, websocket, async-await, python-asyncio

1. Backgound

To avoid defining functions in `async` way, I have to call `ws.send_json` with `run_async` (see the below `server.py`) instead of `await`.
Because of legacy code, in which the biz logic has been implemented with non-async functions, if I change them from non-async functions to async functions, it will impact all the functions in the call hierarchy, which is not acceptable.

2. My Solution

I implemented the `run_async` to call async func without `await` in the same running loop.

3. Problem

Run `run_async(self.ws.send_json, {"message": "Hello"})` successfully, but running `run_async(self.ws.receive_text)` in the same way raises the error: `ValueError: The future belongs to a different loop than the one specified as the loop argument`.

4. Reproduction Steps

(1). Run `server.py` with an ASGI web server e.g. `uvicorn server:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9000`.

server.py

```
import asyncio
import threading
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket

app = FastAPI()

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(ws: WebSocket):
    await ws.accept()
    content = await ws.receive_text()
    print(content)
    inner_instance = InnerClass(ws)
    inner_instance.do_something()
    await ws.close()


class InnerClass:
    def __init__(self, ws):
        self.ws = ws

    # To avoid defining an async function, I have to call ws.send_json with run_async instead of await.
    def do_something(self):
        run_async(self.ws.send_json, {"message": "Hello"})

        ###
        # HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        ###
        response = run_async(self.ws.receive_text)
        print(response)


class RunThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, func, args, kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.result = None
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.result = asyncio.run(self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs))


def run_async(func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = None

    if loop and loop.is_running():
        thread = RunThread(func, args, kwargs)
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        return thread.result
    else:
        return asyncio.run(func(*args, **kwargs))
```

(2). Run `client.py` with `python client.py`, input any text and press `Enter` to send it to server side. The server side received it, sent back `Hello`, and then try to receive again, which causes error.

client.py

```
import sys
import json
import time
import websocket
from websocket import WebSocketApp
import _thread as thread
class WebSocketClient(object):
    def __init__(self, url: str='ws://localhost:9000'):
        self.url = url
        self.ws = None
    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        print(f"Server message: {message}")
    def on_open(self, ws):
        print("####### on_open #######")
        thread.start_new_thread(self.run, ())
    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        print("####### on_error #######")
        print("error: %s" % error)
    def run(self, *args):
        while True:
            input_msg = input("Your Message(Enter 'close' to shutdown):\n")
            if input_msg == "close":
                self.ws.close()
                break
            else:
                self.ws.send(input_msg)
            time.sleep(1)
    def start(self):
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws = WebSocketApp(self.url,
                               on_open=self.on_open,
                               on_error=self.on_error,
                               on_message=self.on_message)
        self.ws.run_forever()
if __name__=='__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        url = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        url = 'ws://127.0.0.1:9000/ws'  # default
    WebSocketClient(url).start()
```